# How to pass variables between bash script and Matlab

Tags: linux, bash, matlab

For example in Matlab I have a string `x = 'foo'` so I want to use it in bash script. Or I have in bash script `x =$'foo'` so I want to use `x` in Matlab. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I can't tell you about matlab, but in Octave all is simple.

For example, to pass bash variable to octave you just do so:

```
Xmax=10; echo "x=[1:$Xmax]; sin(x)" | octave -q
ans =

 Columns 1 through 8:

   0.84147   0.90930   0.14112  -0.75680  -0.95892  -0.27942   0.65699   0.98936

 Columns 9 and 10:

   0.41212  -0.54402
```

And vice versa:

```
Xmax=$(echo "fprintf(1, '%g', max(sin([1:5])))" | octave -q); echo $Xmax
0.909297
```

Answer (score 2):

You can pass commands to MATLAB via its command-line interface using the `-r` switch, e.g.,

```
matlab -r "x=1:whateverYouWant; y=somethingElse;"
```

See [the UNIX command-line interface documentation](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/matlabunix.html) for more information.

Comment: In case it's not obvious, `-r "x=$x"` interpolates the value of the shell variable `x` into the Matlab script. The double quotes are important; single quotes inhibit variable expansion. Ifethe variable's value requires quoting in Matlab, you have to supply the quotes, too.